# assigning a value to a long long integers using gcc on sparc solaris

Tags: c++, gcc, solaris, sparc, long-long

I came across something that I think rather strange.  The test program

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    long unsigned l = 0x12345678;
    long long unsigned ll =  0x12345678;
    cout<<sizeof(l)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(ll)<<endl;
};
```

output is:

```
hello    
4    
8
```

No surprises there. The `long int` has a size of 4 bytes and the `long long` has a size of 8 bytes.
However, when I change it so that the long long is assigned

```
long long unsigned ll =  0x123456789;
```

at compile time I get

```
error: integer constant is too large for "long" type
```

Now this same test *does* compile if I force a 64 bit build using the option `-m64`. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in GCC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change that to

```
long long unsigned ll = 0x123456789ULL; // notice the suffix
```

Without the suffix, the literal is bigger than the maximum `unsigned long` value on your machine, and that, according to C++03 (but not C++11, which has `long long`), is undefined behavior. This means that anything can happen, including a compile-time error.

It's also worth nothing that there's no `long long` in C++03, so it's not guaranteed to work, you're relying on an extension. You'd probably better be off using C++11 instead.

Answer (score 3):

The thing here is that many people seem to look at a line of code like your:

```
unsigned long long ll = 0x123456789;   /* ANTI-PATTERN! Don't do this! */
```

and reason "oh, the type is `unsigned long long`, so the value is `unsigned long long` and it gets assigned", but that's just not how C works. Literals *have their own type*, that doesn't depend on the context in which they're being used. And the type of integer literals is `int`.

This is the same fallacy as when folks do:

```
const double one_third = 1 / 3;   /* ANTI-PATTERN! Don't do this! */
```

Thinking "the type on the left is `double`, so this should assign 0.3333333...". That's just (again!) not how C works. The types of the literals being divided is still `int`, so the right hand side evaluates to exactly 0, which is then converted to `double` and stored in the `one_third` variable.

For some reason, this behavior is deeply non-intuitive to many people, which is why there are many variants of the same question.